# Laravel Validation with or

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a laravel validation that needs to match one of the 3 regex's

```
 $validatedData = $request->validate([

        'BCH-address' => 'regex:/^([13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34})/',
        'BCH-address' => 'regex:/^((bitcoincash:)?(q|p)[a-z0-9]{41})/',
        'BCH-address' => 'regex:/^((BITCOINCASH:)?(Q|P)[A-Z0-9]{41})$/',

    ]),
```

Is there a way to use a OR condition for the validation??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add rule https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-rule-objects and there your logic,
 or use closure https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures
 or make it as separate rule https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-extensions

Comment: Thank you, Closures is what I have been looking for. #Legend!

Comment: @TonySawlwin Let me do that for you. :)