# Laravel validations with "or" condition

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to make an input validation in Laravel with a somewhat complex "or" condition.

I need the validator to validate the input (let it pass) if its value is present in a specific table or if its value is "other".

So far, I have:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [

    ...

    'doc_organization' => ['required_with:rb_regist,doctor, exists:user_organizations,full_name'], // TODO: must exist in user_organizations table or be "other"
    'doc_custom_organization' => ['required_if:doc_organization,other', 'max:160'],

    ...
```

I took a look at Laravel's custom validation rules, conditionally adding rules, and so forth, as well as these posts:

[Laravel Validation with or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644122/laravel-validation-with-or)

[Validation rules required_if with other condition (Laravel 5.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320292/validation-rules-required-if-with-other-condition-laravel-54)

But I can't seem to come up with a custom rule in which I don't query the whole table to know if the name exists (in case it is not "other"). That would make the rule too complex for its purpose.

The other solution I have is to add an entry named "other" in the user_organizations table, which is not ideal.

Am I missing something?
How can I make the condition I want without a complex custom validation rule?

Thank you very much.

Comment: dont send the `full_name` from the front, just the ID. The options `other` would be not to send any ID (empty/null). In that case, using exists is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since "other" is just a value and not a record in your database you can simply "twist it" a bit to something like:

```
'doc_organization' => ['nullable|required_with:rb_regist,doctor, exists:user_organizations,full_name'],
```

The twist is that before your `Validator` you can have a simple check in your requested value like:

```
if($request->doc_organization == "other"){
  $request->merge(['doc_organization' => null]);
}
```

And inject `null` value to the field inside the request.

Having done that you will comply with "nullable" option which will allow you to pass through.